# Replace original ko.xz module in CentOS 8 with patched module

Tags: centos, compiling, kernel-modules

I'm facing a problem with my wifi (Intel Wireless-AC 9462 “No WiFi Adapter Found”). My question is posted in [`forums.centos.org`](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=74896&sid=7185c1e22992209f59f29b27c6795d21).

According to one message on [www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg194071.html) is a bug, and this [patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=db5cce1afc8d2475d2c1c37c2a8267dd0e151526) must be applied.

My solution is to recompile the module according to [wiki.centos.org](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/BuildingKernelModules).

I found a video youtube about of  [CentOS Build Kernel Modules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kAcX9BswuA).

I take a copy of [my kernel version (4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64)](http://vault.centos.org/8.2.2004/BaseOS/Source/SPackages/kernel-4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.src.rpm) and according to bug report, take changes from [kernel 5.4 version](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.4.49.tar.xz).

And I created my fixed kernel module (`iwlwifi.ko.xz`) in my Centos located on

```
/lib/modules/4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko.xz
```

Now, I need to backup it (the **`original`**`iwlwifi.ko.xz`) and replace it.

My situation is this:

```
[root@centos iwlwifi]# pwd
/lib/modules/4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi
[root@centos iwlwifi]# ls -al
total 724
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   4096 Jun 28 18:44 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Jun 26 20:40 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 20:40 dvm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 616856 Jun 28 18:44 iwlwifi.ko
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 103560 Jun 10 06:23 iwlwifi.ko.xz
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Jun 26 20:40 mvm
[root@centos iwlwifi]#
```

As you can see the recent built version is `iwlwifi.ko`

Trying to remove the original

```
[root@centos iwlwifi]# rmmod -v iwlwifi.ko.xz
rmmod: ERROR: Module iwlwifi is in use by: iwlmvm
[root@centos iwlwifi]#
```

Obviously I can force it and remove it, but I need to enable again the `iwlmvm` module.

**What and secure Steps that I need to do (remove the faulty module `iwlwifi.ko.xz` module and install my recent fixed module and enable the untouched `iwlmvm` module)**?

Answer (score 0):

1. Linux removes modules by their name/alias, not by their filesystem module filename, i.e. you must run

```bsh
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
```

2. Having two modules, module.ko and module.ko.xz can confuse your depmod/modprobe utilities because they are both valid module filenames. Please rename the old module to some extension which is known not to be a kernel module, e.g.

`iwlwifi.ko.xz.original` or `iwlwifi.ko.xz.bak`

3. Now you can modprobe the new patched module - hopefully it'll work.